# Why are orphans called orphans?

Tags: orphaned-blocks, stale-block

An orphan does not have parents. On the other hand an orphaned block has a parent but no children. So shouldn't it be called barren rather than orphan?

Comment: Orphan blocks *can* have children. They just don't have as many children as the best chain.

Comment: That's not the origin of the term though, see the linked answer.